# React Native CLI

Tags: react-native, kotlin, gradle, android-activity, javac

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
> w: Detected multiple Kotlin daemon sessions at build\kotlin\sessions

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings89 actionable tasks: 61 executed, 28 up-to-date
D:\rnclasses\navdrawCli\drawyernav\android\app\src\main\java\com\drawyernav\MainActivity.java:9:
error: cannot find symbol
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
^
symbol:   class Bundle
location: class MainActivity
Note: D:\rnclasses\navdrawCli\drawyernav\android\app\src\debug\java\com\drawyernav\ReactNativeFlipper.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
1 error

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)
- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4m 24s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
D:\rnclasses\navdrawCli\drawyernav\android\app\src\main\java\com\drawyernav\MainActivity.java:9:
error: cannot find symbol
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
^
symbol:   class Bundle
location: class MainActivity
Note: D:\rnclasses\navdrawCli\drawyernav\android\app\src\debug\java\com\drawyernav\ReactNativeFlipper.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
1 error

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)
- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4m 24s

```
at makeError (D:\rnclasses\navdrawCli\drawyernav\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
at D:\rnclasses\navdrawCli\drawyernav\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (D:\rnclasses\navdrawCli\drawyernav\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
at async Command.handleAction (D:\rnclasses\navdrawCli\drawyernav\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:142:9)
```

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
PS D:\rnclasses\navdrawCli\drawyernav> ./gradlew build --warning-mode all

i am trying to solve this problem  i am new in development

Comment: i tried two times. it is not working

Answer (score 0):

delete the .gradle folder from /android
and again  npm start
and react-native run-android